# Leer mas de un modelo de entrenamiento para face recognizer

Tags: python, opencv, cv2

El programa es de reconocimiento facial, pero como el entrenamiento pesaba mucho decidí dividirlo en 2 modelos, ahora quiero cargar ambos modelos de entrenamiento para que me reconozca ambos rostros, la cámara llega a abrir y seguidamente me aparece el siguiente error:

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-1i5nllza\opencv\modules\core\src\norm.cpp:1082: error: (-215:Assertion failed) _src1.sameSize(_src2) in function 'cv::norm'

este es el codigo:

```
import cv2
import os

# Ruta donde están guardadas las imagenes
ruta_almacenamiento = "Ruta donde estan cargadas las imagenes que se entrenaron (esto me servirá para mas adelante tomar los nombres de las carpetas con los rostros de las personas)"
Lista_personas = os.listdir(ruta_almacenamiento)
print("Lista de personas: ", Lista_personas)

# Establecer el metodo que se utilizara para el reconocimiento facial
face_recognizer = cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()

# Leyendo el modelo
face_recognizer.read('modeloEigenFace_r.xml')
face_recognizer.read('modeloEigenFace_p.xml')

# Acceder a la camara y poder grabar o cargar un video
captura = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW) # video en vivo

detectar_rostro = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

while True:
    res, video = captura.read()
    if res == False:
        break

    imagen_gris = cv2.cvtColor(video, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    copia_video = imagen_gris.copy()
    rostros = detectar_rostro.detectMultiScale(imagen_gris, 1.3, 5)

    for (x, y, w, h) in rostros:
        rostro = copia_video [y:y+h,x:x+w]
        rostro = cv2.resize(rostro, (150,150), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        resultado = face_recognizer.predict(rostro) 
        
        cv2.putText(video, f"{resultado}", (x, y-5), 1, 1.3,(255, 255, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

        # EigenFaces

        if resultado[1] < 5000:  
            cv2.putText(video, f"{Lista_personas[resultado[0]]}",(x,y-25),2,1.1,(0,255,0),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.rectangle(video, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        else:
            cv2.putText(video,"Desconocido",(x,y-20),2,0.8,(0,0,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.rectangle(video, (x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)

    cv2.imshow("video", video)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

captura.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: hacer que reconozca dos modelos a la vez es posible pero para ello necesitas las dos instancias de `face_recognizer = cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()
` porque tienes dos modelos